# Set certain position of FlxSprite's loadgraphic method

Tags: haxe, haxeflixel

I have a 122 * 16 image.
It has seven colors, and I use only one color per block.

But, `loadGraphic()` in the `FlxSprite` class just uses `width` and `height`.

How do I use certain position of image?

For example, if I choose 0, `loadGraphic()` picks up the position width, height(0 to 15, 16), choose 1, (17 ~ 31, 16)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you use an animation but change the current frame manually? Something like this:

```
var sprite = new FlxSprite(100, 100);
sprite.loadGraphic("assets/image.png", true, 122, 16);
sprite.animation.add("my_animation", [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 0, false);
sprite.animation.play("my_animation", true, 0);
//sprite.animation.paused = true;
sprite.animation.frameIndex = 2; // The frame you want to display
```